Showing a string variable in pyspark sql
How to use spark sql to get a variable.
I have a table called
delta.`first/merchant/loaddate=04-02-2024`

and the last part of my table is the latest data .
I want to somehow get the latest data and put it in the spark. So it will always load the latest.
So I did the following
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(a)
tableName = "delta." + "`first\merchant\loaddate=" + a + '`'

then I do the following
df = spark.sqk(
'''
select 
*
from 
{0}
'''.format(table)

But it does not seem to show the table when I call df.show().

Considering your expected output, two things has to be worked on:
delta.`first/merchant/loaddate=04-02-2024`


The output result has date and it is in format %m-%d-%Y, so please use

today = datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')


You have used backslash instead of forward one.

tableName = "delta." + "`first/merchant/loaddate=" + a + '`'

Could you please try now.
